# How to count available and not available room

Tags: excel

Please i need to count available and not available room depends on checkin and checkout dates.

For example:
I've sheet like this:

```
Room1 checkin 1-1-2021 checkout 5-5-2021
Room2 checkin 2-2-2021 checkout 9-9-2021
Room3 checkin 10-10-2021 checkout 5-12-2021
```

I need cells like this:

```
Available rooms now: 2
Available rooms: room1, room3
Not available rooms now: 1
Not available rooms now: room2
```

Comment: If your sheet now has 5 columns (assumption),, then you can add a 6th column with the value `=IF(AND(NOW()>=C2,NOW()<=E2),"not available","available")`.  This will show if the room is available, or not.  Using the function `COUNTIF()` you can do a count of them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Formulas used here are:

- Available rooms now:

  ```
  =IF(NOW()>C2,1,0)+IF(NOW()>C3,1,0)+IF(NOW()>C4,1,0)
  ```
- Available rooms:

  ```
  =CONCATENATE(IF(NOW()>C2,CONCATENATE(A2,", "),""),IF(NOW()>C3,"Room 2, ",""),IF(NOW()>C4,"Room 3",""))
  ```
- Not available rooms now:

  ```
  =COUNTA(A2,A3,A4)-F1
  ```
- Not available rooms now:

  ```
  =CONCATENATE(IF(NOW()<C2,CONCATENATE(A2,", "),""),IF(NOW()<C3,CONCATENATE(A3,", "),""),IF(NOW()<C4,CONCATENATE(A4,""),""))
  ```